# How to give weights to each row in Logistic Regression in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, logistic-regression, weighted

We are using Spark 1.3.1 I have gone through the spark docs and found out that we cannot give weight to each row in data for Logistic Regression. Is there any simple way so that I can include weights in Logistic Regression in spark? or is this facility being planned in spark for the coming future?

PS: I am not talking about initial weights. I am talking about weighted Logistic Regression.

Comment: can you share your code ? what you are doing write now?

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible for Logistic Regression

```
model = LogisticRegression()
model.setWeightCol(weight_column_name)
```